# Does spring-data-elasticsearch not supports @NotNull or @NotEmpty annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm now working on the latest spring-data-elasticsearch with `spring-boot 2.4.5`, and I just trying to validate my entity(which will be mapped into documents on my elastic-search cluster) with Spring validation annotations like `@NotNull`, `@NotEmpty`, and so on.

However, these annotations aren't working; even if I passed the null to the field(which has marked with `@NotNull`), the error hasn't occurred.

Here's my entity for the Document :

```java
@Builder
@Document(indexName = "testidx", createIndex = false)
public class Book implements Persistable<String> {
    @Id
    private final String _id;

    @NotNull
    @CreatedDate
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.basic_date_time)
    private final Instant regTime;

    @NotNull // this annotations aren't working
    private final String bookName;

    // ...
}
```

I'm trying to find some use-cases on the official references, but I cannot find any.
Does spring-data-elasticsearch not supports Spring validation annotations?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it does not support that (and never did).

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Thanks for letting me know!